# Matroska supported formats

Tags: audio, video, time, matroska, container

So suppose I want to store a variety of time-synced data as a kind of "session", say.  Like, say I have several video recorders recording video at the same time, as well as a few microphones, still-image cameras, a number of sensors recording like seismology data or UV levels or what have you, and a couple keyboards and push-buttons for good measure.  The idea would be that all these data streams could be associated with timestamps and/or time intervals, named, and stored together in one file.  I read that the Matroska format stores a wide variety of media; how many of the above could it reasonably store?  (It might be nice if you could, say, tag the data streams with locations, too, but that's a nice-to-have.)  I've read parts of the wiki entry and the Matroska FAQ and surrounding site, but I'd rather not have to read the entire spec to tease out how feasible this all is.  (Comments are welcome about what format *would* make the most sense for this.)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically: As many as you like!

As mkv is an open source container, its limits keep changing every release. It also depends on whether the user community have use for so many streams of data (audio/video).

mkv easily support multiple audio, video and subtitle streams.

You can check up on more here: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12867/combine-multiple-videos-as-separate-streams-in-one-mkv-file